# "На ощупь" или "наощупь"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать слово "на ощупь" (или "наощупь")? По идее, это наречие и можно заменить синонимом, значит, слитно?

Comment: Не совсем понял, про какие синонимы речь. Я знаю такое правило для приставки/частицы "НЕ". Типа можно ли подобрать синоним без "НЕ". А это что за правило?

Answer (score 13):

Выбрать правильную форму написания "на ощупь" можно не только по словарям, но и просто решив орфографическую задачу.

1. Слово "ощупь" существует, но это еще не значит, что "на ощупь" должно писаться раздельно, для сравнения: встреча - навстречу, истина - поистине.
2. Предлог может соединяться с существительным, образуя наречие со слитным написанием, но это происходит в особых случаях: во-первых, чтобы исключить предметное значение существительного (идти навстречу - надеяться на встречу); во-вторых, чтобы исключить неправильное понимание падежа (например, "взять напрокат" - это взять "как", а не "зачем").
3. В нашем случае перед наречным выражением "на ощупь" такие задачи не ставятся, поэтому оно сохраняет статус обстоятельственного существительного в форме В.п.  со значением направленности на способ восприятия предмета: на глаз, на слух, на вкус, на ощупь.

Comment: Ваш ответ самый интересный и эмоционально нейтральный. Раздражает, когда отвечающий корчит из себя умника.

Comment: Нейтральность — конечно, хорошо, но не хватает ссылок на авторитетные источники. У **behemothus**, хоть [ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/2497/177334) (v4) и начинается со вздоха, есть хотя бы цитата из Розенталя.

Answer (score 7):

Господи, надо ж так всё запутать.

Слово **ощупь** есть!

ОЩУПЬ, -и; ж. < На ощупь. в зн. нареч. 1.
С помощью осязания, по впечатлению от ощупывания, прикосновения. Шершавая на ощупь поверхность. Найти очки на ощупь. -2.
Вслепую, наугад. Идти на ощупь. Искать решение проблемы на ощупь. Вести машину на ощупь.

По современным нормам "на ощупь" пишется раздельно. В прежние времена (у Даля, например) правильным считалось слитное написание. К сожалению, не знаю, когда норма изменилась. Видимо не так давно, поскольку многие достаточно грамотные люди считают слитное написание правильным.

(+) 18.08.2016

Фантастика. Никак не могут вопрос закрыть, на какую-то реформу грамматики(!!!) ссылаются.

Нате вам Розенталя, ("Справочник по орфографии...")

> Пишутся раздельно употребленные в наречном значении сочетания имен
>   существительных с предлогами:
>
> ....
>
> на, например: на бегу, на весу, на виду, на лету, на скаку, на ходу;
>   на вес, на вид, на вкус, на глаз, на глазок, на грех, на диво, на
>   зависть, **на ощупь**, на редкость, на славу, на смех;

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/35.htm#
§58. п.3

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108292/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus----).

Answer (score 2):

Пишем раздельно. Сложности могут возникнуть из-за наречий с подобными приставками (вслепую, наугад, наотрез и т. д.), которые пишутся слитно. «На ощупь» всегда пишется раздельно. https://mel.fm/kak_pravilno/7658294-feel

Или вот ещё ссылка на Розенталя: "Пишутся раздельно (в два слова) употребленные в наречном значений сочетания существительных с предлогами:... **на**: на бегу, на весу, на виду, на лету, на скаку, на ходу, на вес, на вид, на вкус, на глаз, на глазок, на грех, на диво, на зависть, **на ощупь**, на редкость, на славу, на смех; на днях, на радостях, на рысях, на сносях, (стоять) на часах;..." http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1948

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо помню правило от Д.Розенталя: наречия, образованные от существительных и имеющие предлоги "без, до, на, с, под", пишутся раздельно: без удержу, до зарезу, на ощупь, с размаху, под стать, даже если без предлогов не употребляются

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что здесь тоже возможны варианты (как и в случае с "на встречу - навстречу". Если имеется в виду ощущение, как метод исследования (по аналогии с "на вид", "на взгляд", "на вкус"), то напрашивается раздельное написание (раз уж существует слово "ощупь"). Если же имеет место чистое наречие, отвечающее на вопрос "как?" и не требующее больше никаких дополнений/пояснений (по аналогии с "навскидку", "вприсядку", "наперекосяк"), то, действительно, напрашивается слитное написание - причём, при употреблении как в прямом, так и в переносном смысле. Например: "Он пробирался по пещере наощупь." или "Он продвигался в своих исследованиях наощупь." Язык ведь живой...